# App is installed and has two icons

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest

I made a android app and it worked very well, but there are two icons in my device screen. I think it could be a AndroidManifest problem. Any idea what it could be?

This my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pk.aeh.ideos.taa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
           <activity
        android:name=".Ghinho_congviecActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Nhap_congviecActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Sua_congviecActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Quizzes"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PlayGame" />
    <activity android:name=".Result" />

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Press menu key on your device home screen and Rearrange icon . then check :)

Comment: i dont understand. what do you mean? i Rearranged icon but it's still there, two things.

Comment: `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` means that the activity should appear in the Launcher as a top-level application hence you get two icons. Read docs for clarification [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make these changes to your `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".Ghinho_congviecActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="Nhap_congviecActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name="Sua_congviecActivity"></activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Quizzes"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

I am assuming that the `Activity` with the attribute `android:label="@string/app_name"` might be your main activity.

Answer (score 9):

This could be because you have declared two activities as MAIN and LAUNCHER

```
         <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
```

in your `Androidmanifest.xml` file. You need to have only one activity with these intent filters so that when the app is installed the system will know which activity is to be used as the main launcher activity.

Answer (score 6):

It is. You have two of these:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Get rid of the one you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have changed your package name and installed it twice with different package names.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intent filter of one the activity and it would work perfectly.!

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file should only have one activity with below Intent Filter, Activity which you want to have an icon:

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

Based on your description, it sounds like two activities have this line. Check your Manifest...

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare only one Intent filter in the activity, on AndroidManifest.

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

If you used two or more intent filter in AndroidManifest, then you will have display 2 app icon, So remove it & set one intent filter.

I hove this is usedful to you.